# Row span on nested CSS-Grid

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having an Angular 2 app and in one component I have a nested grid. One main grid with a heading and each row is another grid, added by an *ngFor, and I don´t know how many rows I will get.

If a certain occasion is fulfilled, I want span the rows to have some blocks instead of lines.

CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 80px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 20px;
} 
.h-item1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    background-color: red;
  }
.h-item2 { 
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: pink;
  }
.h-item3 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: violet;
  } 

.sub-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2 item3';
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;

  }
  .item1 {
    grid-area: item1;
    background-color: lime;
  }

  .item2 {
    grid-area: item2;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .item3 {
    grid-area: item3;
    background-color: blue; 
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="h-item1">1</div>
  <div class="h-item2">2</div>
  <div class="h-item3">3</div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-grid">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The codepen, of how the grid looks like is here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgKwxr

I would like to have the yellow column to span the first two rows and then from the third to the end for example. Is there any way to accomplish this, using this kind of grid usage?

In the end the grid should look like that:

```
header1 header2 header2
sub1    sub2    sub3
sub1            sub3
sub1    sub2    sub3 
sub1            sub3 
sub1            sub3
sub1            sub3
```

where the sub2 are spanned.

Comment: Can you please draw an image how the grid should look like? I don't get it.

Comment: @Tommy: I made an example, so the sub2 column should span the rows, but since the rows are all grids itself, I don´t know how to do that